# Update Label based on dynamic buttons clicked on Stack Layout in Python and Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to update text in label based on dynamic buttons clicked in stack layout.
Here is my main.py code :

```
kivy.require('2.1.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout

class SPKList(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(0, 500):
            width = dp(250)
            height = dp(150)
            b = Button (
                text=str(i+1),
                size_hint=(None,None),
                size=(width,height),
                font_size=dp(20)
                )
            self.add_widget(b)

class MainFrame(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SPKMonitorApp(App):
    pass


SPKMonitorApp().run()
```

and here is the SPKMonitor.kv code :

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
MainFrame:
<MainFrame@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        id:room1
        text:"This is Free Space"
        size_hint: 1, .3
        font_size: "20dp"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"horizontal"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: .4, 1
            Label:
                id:room2
                text:"This is Free Space"
                font_size: "20dp"
            Button:
                id:submitButton
                text:"SUBMIT"
                size_hint: 1, .2
                font_size: "20dp"
        SPKFieldView:

<SPKDetailView@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "No. SPK"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"


<SPKFieldView@ScrollView>:
    SPKList:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height

<SPKList>:
```

and here is the UI :
[image]

Please help me update the text in label with ID: **room2** to any number I clicked in the right side buttons (the stack layout)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a method, triggered by the `Button`, that does what you want. Just modify your `SPKList` slightly:

```
class SPKList(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(0, 500):
            width = dp(250)
            height = dp(150)
            b = Button (
                text=str(i+1),
                size_hint=(None,None),
                size=(width,height),
                font_size=dp(20),
                on_release=self.do_button  # added
                )
            self.add_widget(b)

    def do_button(self, button):
        # set the text of the Label
        App.get_running_app().root.ids.room1.text = button.text
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is very helpful but what I wanted to change is Id's room2 instead of room1. The label for room2 is inside another layout

Comment: Just change `App.get_running_app().root.ids.room1.text = button.text` to `App.get_running_app().root.ids.room2.text = button.text`.